# Как поменять местами содержимое файлов?

Tags: android, kotlin

Поменять местами содержимое файлов. Имеется код:

```
perform.setOnClickListener {

        val path1 = File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "$filepath")
        val path2 = File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "$filepath2")
        val fileExists1 = path1.exists()
        val fileExists2 = path2.exists()
        if(fileExists1) {
        }
        else filepath.setText("error", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
        if(fileExists2) {
        }
        else filepath2.setText("error", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
    }
```

Comment: скопировать а потом переименовать

Comment: Ну имеется код, и что с ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файлы расположены в одном разделе ФС (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` в обоих случаях намекает что так и есть), можно переименовать:

```
    val path1 = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "$filepath")
    val path2 = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "$filepath2")
    // здесь проверки исходных файлов
    // ....

    // мы не можем сразу переименовать один файл в другой, так как он существует
    // поэтому должны освободить одно имя
    // для этого создаём временное имя и переименовываем первый в него
    val tempPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "_tmp")
    path1.renameTo(tempPath)

    // второй в первый
    path2.renameTo(path1)

    // временный во второй
    tempPath.renameTo(path2)
```

Все проверки оставляю на вашей совести

Если в разных разделах - тогда только копировать.
Принцип тот же: через временный файл, но если файлы не большие, то можно без него - загрузить оба в оперативную память и записать наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм обмена значениями двух переменных при помощи вспомогательной:

```
tmp = a;  
a = b;  
b = tmp;
```

Предположим есть некие функции:

```
String NameOf (File file); (* возвращает имя файла *)
void Rename (File file, String name); (* переименовывает файл *)
```

Алгоритм обмена содержимого файлов будет будет аналогичен вышеприведенному:

```
String name1 = NameOf (file1);  
Rename (file1, NameOf (file2));  
Rename (file2, name1);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой ответ, хотя бы добавив подсветку в код

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/499940)

Comment: Да вот тоже думаю, но не знаю как оформить.По сути можно даже просто переименовать их, но немного не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: @vanyamba-electronics Я только предложил общую концепцию алгоритма - не обменивать содержимое файлов, а поступить как при обмене данными между массивами: можно не копировать поэлементно все данные, а просто поменять указатели местами. Аналогично и с файлами - переименовать первый во второй, а второй в первый. Я просто не знаком с kotlin'ом - готовую реализацию не смогу предложить, к сожалению, - лишь основную идею...

Comment: @DaemonHK Это как бы псевдокод, просто поясняющий основную идею... Я могу, конечно, выделить разметкой алгоритм обмена значениями двух переменных в целых три строки... но это примерно как алгоритм присвоения x = 2...

Answer (score 0):

Для обмена значений переменных существует еще и арифметический метод, без использования дополнительной переменной:

```
a = a + b; 
b = a - b; 
a = a - b;
```

К сожалению, к файлам такая простая арифметика не применима, если только не использовать некие низкоуровневые аналоги указателей для файловых систем...